# Expo camera taking picture crashing application

Tags: javascript, ios, camera, expo

I'm currently using the expo camera in my application on iOS.

The app crashes when I try to save the image like this.

```js
takePicture = async function() {
    this.camera.takePictureAsync().then(data => {
      FileSystem.moveAsync({
            from: data,
            to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${this.state
              .photoId}.jpg`,
          }).then(() => {
            this.setState({
              photoId: this.state.photoId + 1,
            });
            Vibration.vibrate();
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error : " + err);
          });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    Vibration.vibrate();
    console.log("Taking pic");
  }
```

In addition the Vibration.vibrate() doesn't actually vibrate the phone. I receive an error earlier in the execution here:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'photos'
    ).catch(e => {
      console.log(e, 'Directory exists');
    });
  }
```

The error just says

```js
[Error: Directory 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/X/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/X/photos' could not be created.]
```

Is there anyone else who has experienced the same issue? If anyone is able to let me know how to add the vibration too this would be fantastic. I've added it in the top of the file as:

```js
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Slider,
  Image,
  Picker,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  Vibration,
} from 'react-native';
```

EDIT: I've solved the issue with saving to the cameraroll. The issue with the vibration still stands.

Thanks

Comment: you could post the code of how you are doing to save to the cameraroll

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem you describe, although you solved it via a workaround by saving it to cameraroll, I would suggest you post the edited code to keep the question correctly up to date.

**FileSystem Issue**

Addressing the FileSystem error issue, the original code should work as it is, but you could check:

1. If the expo app has appropriate file access permissions (should be automatic via the expo library, but try updating the expo app). Documentation on FileSystem can be found here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem.html
2. You may need to create the intermediate directories (i.e. photos):

like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
      `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos`,
      {
        intermediates: true, // creates intermediate directories
      }
    )
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

**Vibration Issue**

The vibration problem is probably caused by a bug in react-native as described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8955#issuecomment-353373616

As a workaround you could vibrate before setting the state i.e:

```
takePicture = async function() {
  if (this.camera) {
    const picture = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
    const pictureFile = await FileSystem.moveAsync(
      {
        from: picture.uri,
        to: `${
          FileSystem.documentDirectory
        }photos/Photo_${this.state.photoId}.jpg`
      }
    ).catch(err => console.error(err));
    Vibration.vibrate();
    console.log("Pic taken", this.state.photoId);
    return this.setState({
      photoId: this.state.photoId + 1
    });
  }
};
```